# Extracting integers only from vector of doubles

Tags: matlab, vector, integer

I have a time-vector `T` in MATLAB consisting of `doubles` from time `0` to my end-time (some large number), looking like this:

```
[...
2.4485;
2.7147;
3;
3.2986;
4;
4.3759;
4.7976;
5;
...]
```

I also have a vector `A` with collected data for every time element in `T` (they are equally long).

Now, I would like to extract all the integer elements from `T` and the corresponding elements in `A` so that I have a data-pair for each second 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

There is no regularity in how often it comes a time-point with non-zero decimals. If it were not for `A`, I could of course just create an integer-time vector using `linspace`, but the problem is: to know which elements in `A` to skip.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: So the desired output for the above data `[3 4 5]`? If so, please add this to your question....

Answer (score 2):

```
B = A((T-round(T))<10*eps());
```

this checks whether an entry of `T` is equal to the rounded version of itself (within a specified tolerance, in this case I used [`10*eps()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), and if true, the entry is an integer. Thus it creates a logical matrix, which is used to index `A`, returning to `B` only values that correspond to `T` integers.

Comment: Or just interpolate the corresponding signal on an integer grid to get rid of all these problems ^^

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all the answers! In the end find(mod(T,1)==0) worked out fine for me.